# More than one DbContext named 'NewProject.Models.DbContext' was found Specify which one to use by providing its fully qualified name using exact case

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, asp.net-core-2.1

I was developing a Web-App with Asp.Net Core 2.1 . After I added the new identity with scaffolder it generated me these codes:

**Code generated in IdentityStartup.cs**

```
[assembly:HostingStartup(typeof(ShareAndCare.Areas.Identity.IdentityHostingStartup))]
namespace ShareAndCare.Areas.Identity
{
    public class IdentityHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {

                services.AddDbContext<ShareAndCareContext>(options =>
                   options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer(
                       context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ShareAndCareContextConnection")));

                services.AddIdentity<ShareAndCareUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ShareAndCareContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

                services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();               

            });

        }
    }
}
```

**Code generated in Startup.cs**

```
    namespace ShareAndCare
    {
        public class Startup
        {
            public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
            {
                Configuration = configuration;
            }

            public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
                {
                    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
                });            

                services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);            
            }    
            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
            {
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                }
                else
                {
                    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                    app.UseHsts();
                }

                app.UseHttpsRedirection();
                app.UseStaticFiles();
                app.UseAuthentication();
                app.UseCookiePolicy();

                app.UseMvc(routes =>
                {
                    routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                });                
            }   
        }
    }
```

This was working fine until I wanted to scaffold a model with controller and views using EF. When set up everything and click ok I was getting an error saying : **More than one DbContext named 'ShareAndCare.Models.ShareAndCareContext' was found. Specify which one to use by providing its fully qualified name using its exact case.** I checked all the folders and namespaces but there was no problem there, there was only one context with that name. So what was the problem ?

Comment: Ctrl+F -> "ShareAndCareContext"

Comment: I found the solution but what you mean by Ctrl+F ?

Comment: i mean "Are you sure, that there is only one 'ShareAndCareContext' class? Have you try to find all occurrences of 'ShareAndCareContext' string in yout project files?"

Comment: Yes mate I tried everything and checked every namespace even if I created a new context it was giving the same error. Like I mentioned below problem was with the Context being added in Configure method of the IdentityStartup.cs

Comment: Ok, mate. I see, that you already found a solution. My comment was just a guess, and was posted 5 minutes before your answer.

Comment: Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm leaving that question and answer here so people don't go crazy looking for all possible solutions manually like I did. I found out that adding the context in the Configure method of **IdentityHostingStartup.cs** was causing the problem. I changed the place where I added the context to the Configure method of **Startup.cs** and it was working just fine.

```
namespace ShareAndCare
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });            

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            services.AddDbContext<ShareAndCareContext>(options =>
                   options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer(
                       Configuration.GetConnectionString("ShareAndCareContextConnection")));

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });                
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try this I get an error saying The entity type IdentityHostingStartup requires a primary key defined.  Has anyone run into this?

Comment: Thank you very much. My issue was same and solved it to move code from IdentityHostingStartup.cs to startup.cs

Comment: Brilliant, thanks.. Solved my identical issue with .Net Core 3 too.. Why does the identity code insist on having its own startup. I'm sure it may have a purpose for larger projects using areas... but complicates it... and causes hassle like this.

Comment: he meant he **Move** the init code in **IdentityHostingStartup.cs** into **Startup.cs** *public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)* at code line `services.AddDbContext<projecctnameeABC>(...);` there. 
Jesus, just state it clearly instead of slamming whole paragraph of code.

Comment: Thank you for leaving the solution as well!

Answer (score 1):

I just deleted the 2 files:

1. Areas/Identity/Data/APNameIdentityDbContext.cs and
2. Areas/Identity/IdentityHostingStartup.cs

This fixed the error!

Comment: How? The question doesn't say anything about an `APNameIdentityDbContext`.

Answer (score 0):

In my Case I was adding
`services.AddDbContext<DBContext>`
but instead my DBContext name was

`ApplicationDBContext`.

Changed my Name in Startup.cs and it worked

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]));
        }
```

Hope this helps someone :)