# When trying to scaffold a controller I am getting an error saying more than one dbcontext was found

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dbcontext, scaffolding

I am trying to scaffold a controller using API controller with actions using entity framework. After I select the model class and the Data context class it says it has found a duplicate KPContext please specify. I never added another kpcontext when I go into my models I do not see another one under the models folder. i do a full search and can't find another KPcontext class. Disclaimer this only happened when I added a few more tables to my db and did a new scaffold of the database with a -force all my old code is working and pulling data correctly but not able to scaffold anymore thanks for any help

Comment: what IDE are you using?

Comment: I suggest you rewrite this question by starting with the initial steps including the exact command you used to scaffold (you can hide the connection string etc) and finish with the issue you are facing

Comment: vs 2017 "Scaffold-DbContext Data Source=mydb;Initial Catalog=mycat;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=true; Connection Timeout=200; Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Force" then when I try to scaffold a controller it gives me the error above

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer in this link [More than one DbContext named 'NewProject.Models.DbContext' was found Specify which one to use by providing its fully qualified name using exact case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51318248/more-than-one-dbcontext-named-newproject-models-dbcontext-was-found-specify-wh). Maybe your problem is the same.

Adding the context in the Configure method of IdentityHostingStartup.cs causes the problem. Instead, you should add the context in Startup.cs. I think it's the bug, I tested with Asp.net Core 2.2 preview 3 (latest at this moment), and I still get that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on the Zaffer's answer and the other thread, issue is still present on Net Core 3.1 Identity templates, make sure you restart VS after moving it to Startup.cs, then it works

Answer (score 0):

Just move the code from `IdentityHostingStartup.cs` to `Startup.cs` and restart Visual Studio, It worked for me. Rebuild and Run. Now scaffolding should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).